# Substitute the '+' (plus) with '-' (dash) for space replacement in URL for OpenSearch

Tags: firefox, search, search-engine, opensearch

I am in the process of generating an OpenSearch plugin for a website.  I am most of the way there, in fact, the plugin works when there is only one word in the search.  I should note that this is not your standard search engine, it provides a map of related keywords to the words in your search.  The issue appears to be that the behavior of this search engine is slightly different than others.  For example, with google your search URL for "project management" appears like this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=project+management
```

Whereas with KwMap your search appears like this:

```
http://www.kwmap.net/project-management.html
```

So my question is whether or not it is possible using OpenSearch to replace the space in the search term with a dash rather than a plus symbol?  Here is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <!-- Created on Wed, 10 Jul 2013 17:26:47 GMT -->
  <ShortName>KwMap</ShortName>
  <Description>A Keyword Map for the Whole Internet</Description>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.kwmap.net/{searchTerms}.html"/>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <moz:SearchForm>http://www.kwmap.net/</moz:SearchForm>
  <Url type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="self"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible, since that would be outside of the standard URL encoding approach. I'm sure kwmap.net must provide a means to take standard query string URLs and rewrite it to their own proprietary format, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be done with Regex.  The closest thing I have found is a discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opensearch/N5_hm58Peqc.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an HTML document that includes OpenSearch autodiscovery link elements uses dashes:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head profile="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
     <!--- ... --->
     <link rel="search"
       type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
       href="http://example.com/content-search.xml"
       title="Content search" />
     <link rel="search"
       type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
       href="http://example.com/comment-search.xml"
       title="Comments search" />
     <!--- ... --->
   </head>
   <body>
   <!--- ... --->
   </body>
  </html>
```

> Various document formats and specifications already support IRIs. Examples include HTML 4.0, XML 1.0 system identifiers, the XLink href attribute, XMLSchema's anyURI datatype, etc. We will also see later that major browsers support the use of IRIs already.

**References**

- [OpenSearch 1.1 Draft 5: Autodiscovery in HTML/XHTML](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1/Draft_5#Autodiscovery_in_HTML.2FXHTML)
- [RFC 3987: Internationalized Resource Identifiers (IRIs)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt)
- [Oasis Tools: CMIS SchemaProject Source - Atom.xsd](http://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/cmis/trunk/SchemaProject/schema/ATOM.xsd)
- [MSDN: Creating an OpenSearch Description File in Windows Federated Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940453)
- [Introducing OpenSearch](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/07/20/introducing-opensearch.html)
- [MDN: Creating OpenSearch plugins for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox)
- [Alfresco Wiki: OpenSearch](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/OpenSearch)
- [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/)